# No Known Conversion Between a typedef array of unsigned chars with std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to push a type defined array of unsigned chars into a vector, but it won't let me it keeps saying there's `no known conversion from unsigned char* to const unsigned char &[13]`.

The actual error message: `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<unsigned char [13]>::push_back(unsigned char*&)’|`

Typedef code:

```
const int BYTE_STRING_LEN = 13;
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef byte bytestring[BYTE_STRING_LEN];
```

Add to vector code:

```
void printNewSolution(bytestring b)
{
    // check against known solutions to see if it's unique
    static std::vector<bytestring> KnownSolutions;
    KnownSolutions.push_back(b);
}
```

EDIT 1:
I need to use raw character arrays because I'm doing bitwise operations on them and each value needs to be 1 byte.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable or copyable, so they can't be stored in `std::vector`.

Comment: Perfect example of why `std::array` or `std::string` is easier to use than raw character arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

const int BYTE_STRING_LEN = 13;
typedef unsigned char byte;

struct bytestring
{
    bytestring(const byte* val)
    {
        memcpy(value, val, sizeof(value));
    }

    bool operator==(const bytestring& other) const
    {
        return memcmp(value, other.value, sizeof(value)) == 0;
    }

    byte value[BYTE_STRING_LEN];
};

void printNewSolution(bytestring b)
{
    // check against known solutions to see if it's unique
    static std::vector<bytestring> KnownSolutions;
    if (std::find(KnownSolutions.begin(), KnownSolutions.end(), b) == KnownSolutions.end())
    {
        std::cout << "new" << std::endl;
        KnownSolutions.push_back(b);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "old" << std::endl;
}
```

Output statements there just to show it's working.

Runnable here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09b6c0ac9889787a

With this solution in hand, it's worth noting that `std::string` is just

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

So if you want to ensure you're using unsigned char, you can use

```
typedef std::basic_string<byte> bytestring;
```

At which point the rest still works:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c5045be3deedf2

Comment: I just ended up using the stl array as a typedef. It was cleaner and allowed me to do it in the same number of lines as my first attempt with a c-style array.